# Get value range for number of bits in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I need to calculate signed value range for some bits count.
For example:

```
bitscount = 4

min value = -2^3;

max value = 2^3 - 1; in bitwise it is (1<<3 - 1)
```

I forgot how to compose bitwise for min value. Please help.

Comment: Well how about `-(1 << 3)`? You already know that `2^3` is `1<<3`, so just negate it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
minValue = -(1 << (bitscount - 1));
maxValue = (1 << (bitscount - 1)) - 1;
```

Comment: this answer has been flagged as low quality answer, please provide some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

> ```
> int bits_count = 4;  // between 2 ~ 32 (I assumed int type is 32bits signed integer)
> int min_value = -(1 << (bits_count - 1));
> int max_value = (1 << (bits_count - 1)) - 1;
> ```

And reference site: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_bitwise_operators_examples.htm